# How can I check if the computer is “busy in fullscreen” on Windows from PHP CLI?

Tags: php, windows

I have a whole system in PHP CLI set up that runs all the time. It checks all kinds of things, among them if certain Twitch streamers are streaming. If they are, a notification is sent to me.

But I can also open my browser directly and go to their stream, which I did up until recently. The reason I stopped doing that is that sometimes, I'm busy watching something in fullscreen or maybe even running an application of some sort in fullscreen mode. In those cases, I don't want it to open a browser and disturb me to that degree.

Which means I need some way to check if the "computer is busy in fullscreen mode". I know that this can be done by normal programs, with the Windows APIs, but I don't have access to those from PHP CLI. Is there some sort of command-line call that can be done or something in order for PHP to be able to get a true/false returned at any time as to whether the computer is in this mode?

Comment: Umm .. make the notification a link that you can click to view if you choose to.

Comment: If you know of the windows API's that give you this information, probably the best course of action is find out how you can call them directly or indirectly from PHP. I know PHP used to have COM, but I figure that's dated now.

Comment: @Evert Well, sadly, I don't even know that...